# OSX - Compiling training tools for Tesseract 4.0 - pango libraries not found

Tags: macos, homebrew, tesseract

I am having trouble getting the configure script to recognise the pango libraries i have installed via Homebrew, which are dependancies for the training tools. So far, I've followed all steps detailed here:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1453

and here:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling#macos

and after running the configure script, I keep on getting these warnings in the output:

> checking for pango >= 1.22.0... no
>
> configure: WARNING: pango 1.22.0 or higher is required, but was not
>   found.
>
> configure: WARNING: Training tools WILL NOT be built.
>
> configure: WARNING: Try to install libpango1.0-dev package.
>
> checking for cairo... no
>
> configure: WARNING: Training tools WILL NOT be built because of
>   missing  cairo library.
>
> configure: WARNING: Try to install libcairo-dev?? package.

The libraries are located where they should be, at /usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.42.4_1

I've tried running the configure script as per the instructions above:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib
```

as well as trying to add the path to the linking flags:

```
./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.42.4_1/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include"
```

and I still can't get the script to see the libraries.

Thanks in advance for any advice on how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like **pango** and/or **cairo** and maybe other libraries depend on **libffi**. **libffi** is called to be keg-only in Homebrew. Even if libffi is installed it is not linked via symbolic-links. When **pkg-config** tries to find a library, it also checks for its **dependencies**. Since **libffi** cannot be located **pkg-config** tells that **cairo** is not available. Therefore, one needs to call

```
brew link libffi --force
```

This should solve the problem without touching anything extra. At least it worked for my case.

Comment: In my case this command produced the following warning: `Refusing to link macOS-provided software: libffi`. However, the provided hint finally did make the trick: `For compilers to find libffi you may need to set: export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most elegant solution to the problem I found:

```
brew install cairo pango icu4c autoconf libffi libarchive libpng
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=\
$(brew --prefix)/lib/pkgconfig:\
$(brew --prefix)/opt/libarchive/lib/pkgconfig:\
$(brew --prefix)/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig:\
$(brew --prefix)/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig:\
$(brew --prefix)/opt/libpng/lib/pkgconfig
./configure
```

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract-4.00#on-macos-mojave-with-homebrew

Comment: This still didn't work for me - same warning as OP -> cannot build training tools.

Comment: In my case I also needed to explicitly add `brew install libpng` and insert `$(brew --prefix)/opt/libpng/lib/pkgconfig` into your export line. Would you like to incorporate that into your answer or (seems unfair) should I add it as a separate answer?

Answer (score 2):

*This is a modified version of the answer provided by Boris [Boris: just say the word and I will delete this].*

Tested on macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra.

None of the pre-existing answers worked for me - I had to explicitly add `libpng` to my brew requirements as given by Boris:

```
brew install cairo pango icu4c autoconf libffi libarchive libpng
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=\
$(brew --prefix)/lib/pkgconfig:\
$(brew --prefix)/opt/libarchive/lib/pkgconfig:\
$(brew --prefix)/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig:\
$(brew --prefix)/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig:\
$(brew --prefix)/opt/libpng/lib/pkgconfig
./configure
```

Note: If you already have some of the above you might rather want to run `brew reinstall` in place of `brew install`, at the risk of damaging other projects.

I didn't need to supply any flags to `configure`.

The aim is of course to get the training tools to compile so that `combine_tessdata`, `wordlist2dawg`, `dawg2wordlist` etc. are available (I haven't found macOS binaries for these anywhere).

The full instructions then become:

```
git clone git@github.com:tesseract-ocr/tesseract.git
git checkout tags/4.1.0

cd tesseract
./autogen.sh

brew install cairo pango icu4c autoconf libffi libarchive libpng
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=\
$(brew --prefix)/lib/pkgconfig:\
$(brew --prefix)/opt/libarchive/lib/pkgconfig:\
$(brew --prefix)/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig:\
$(brew --prefix)/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig:\
$(brew --prefix)/opt/libpng/lib/pkgconfig
./configure

make -j
sudo make install

# -> You should now have access to tesseract

make training
sudo make training-install

# -> You should now have access to the training tools: combine_tessdata, wordlist2dawg, dawg2wordlist, etc.

# If not, check /usr/local/bin/ is on your PATH, i.e.
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH
```

---

**Footnote: How I diagnosed the libpng problem:**

As stated above and [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1453#issuecomment-530743017), the error thrown is not very helpful:

```
make training
Need to reconfigure project, so there are no errors
```

Digging a little deeper, `configure` throws some warnings along the lines of:

```
configure: WARNING: pango 1.22.0 or higher is required, but was not found.
configure: WARNING: Training tools WILL NOT be built.
configure: WARNING: Try to install libpango1.0-dev package.
checking for cairo... no
configure: WARNING: Training tools WILL NOT be built because of missing cairo library.
configure: WARNING: Try to install libcairo-dev?? package.
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
```

I also had one for `cairo`

So you have to run `configure` in debug mode:

```
./configure --enable-debug
```

And check `config.log` by `grep`ing for `pango` (say):

```
$PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "pango >= 1.22.0"
```

That is the line that throws the warning when `configure` is executed.

You can now execute that last line manually:

```
pkg-config --exists --print-errors pango
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_png_create_info_struct
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libPng.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
Abort trap: 6
```

which is how I traced the `libpng` cause. (In my case I had to `reinstall`/re`link` `libpng` because of various long-running clashes associated with `gnuplot`/`octave`/`aquaterm` etc. etc.).

HTH someone

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by copying the pkgconfig files under libffi and icu4c
(find the path by typing brew link libffi icu4c in your terminal)
and pasting them at  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig  and then set

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```